# How to make boost::tuple I/O or boost::fusion I/O work with Qt streams?

Tags: c++, qt, boost, io, tuples

`boost::tuple` I/O and `boost::fusion` I/O is a good feature. They seem to work with only `std` streams. Is there any way to to make `boost::tuple` I/O or `boost::fusion` I/O work with Qt streams? Thanks.

Comment: I think Qt streams read to `char[]`, and `char[]` data to `fusion` I/O with `stringstream`.